# Join a win7 computer to a domain where domain is in remote location

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller, windows-7

I am in GA and need to have several notebooks join a domain where the Domain Controller is in Texas.  Notebooks are Win7 and Domain Controller is 2008 R2.  I have VPN access to the Domain Controller from the Win7 notebook.

Comment: Ok. What is your question?

Comment: What country is GA?

Answer (score 4):

VPN in, then add it to the domain. As long as there's no firewall rule blocking you, you should be able to do this. Unless you have a VPN that can connect when Windows starts (as opposed to login), you'll be in a tight spot with logging in to it with anything other than local accounts. You will also have some issues with group policy.

Are you sure this is what you want to do?

Comment: You can still use domain accounts as long as you can establish a connection once and have the credentials cached. Without a VPN that runs as a service on startup, it will be a PITA, though.

Comment: It does not seem practical to send all of the notebooks to Texas or for me to take them there.
I have figured out how to login to the Texas Domain controller as I have been unable to figure out how to login via the VPN like you could do in XP.  What I do is to login as a local administrator, make the VPN connection and thnn "switch" users to a domain account.  Even though the VPN is "gone" after the switch has completed, it appears to work.  I have done this once and will be experimenting to see if it is readily repeatable.

Comment: It's possible, yes. I'm just not sure it's the solution you're really looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an appliance that has an always on VPN link that way you are natively "on" the company's network.

That seems like a pretty reasonable price/compromise.  It is only listed as an example, you'll want to do some research first to make sure it would be compliant with the VPN appliance on the other end of the tube.

Like has been mentioned, you don't need to always been on the network to use your AD credentials, but firing up a software VPN client every time you want to work using internal network resources can be a pain.